# Showing a map is an automorphism - showing bijectivity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

I have quite a long exercise that I have to solve but I do have the solutions for it. I'm having trouble understanding some steps, however.

Let $G$ be a group. We denote by $x*y$ the product of two elements $x, y \in G$, and by $1$ the neutral element of $G$. Let (Bij$(G), \circ)$ be the group of bijective maps from $G$ to itself. We denote by Aut$(G)$ the subset of Bij$(G)$ consisting of automorphisms of $G$.

The exercise is as follows:  For $g \in G$, we define a map $\rho_g : G \to G$ by setting $\rho_g(x) = g * x * g^{-1}$. Show that $\rho_g$ is an automorphism of $G$.

Well first I have to show that:
$\rho_g(x*y)=\rho_g(x)*\rho_g(y)$.

$\rho_g(x*y)= g * (x * y) * g^{-1} =  g * x * g^{-1}*g * y * g^{-1} = \rho_g(x)*\rho_g(y)$

Now my first question is at this step. Can I always expand $g * (x * y) * g^{-1}$ to $g * x * g^{-1}*g * y * g^{-1}$?

Or why does this work exactly?

Also then showing bijectivity. For injectivity, I checked some other exercises and found that If the kernel is trivial, then it is injective. The solutions to this exercise are as follows:

$\ker(\rho_g) = \{x \in G , g*x*g^{-1}=1\} = \{x \in G , g*1*g^{-1}=1\} = \{1\}$.

Why do I solve this for $1$? Does the kernel not have to be trivial for a map to be injective?

For surjectivity, the proof seems almost too simple. They argue that $\rho_g(x) = y$ has the solution given by $x = g * y * g^{-1}$.

I guess this does make sense although I'm not sure if I can always prove it this way. Can I just always solve for $x$ to prove surjectivity?

Comment: First question: Yes, by associativity of the operation and the properties of the neutral element. [to be more precise: For the neutral element $1$ it holds $g*x=g*x*1=g*x*g^{-1}*g$ ]

Injectivity: I guess $1$ denotes the neutral element here, which would mean, the kernel is trivial, so I don't see a problem here.

Surjectivity: It is that simple. For every $y$ you can choose $x$ exactly the way that $x$ is mapped onto $y$ and that is what has to be shown.

Comment: Regarding the kernel, you might have got confused by the notation. All that has to be shown ist that $x\in \ker(\rho_g)\Leftrightarrow x=1$, which is trivial, since $x\in \ker(\rho_g)\Leftrightarrow gxg^{-1}=1 \Leftrightarrow gx=1*g=g\Leftrightarrow x=1*x=g^{-1}*g*x=g^{-1}*g=1$.

Comment: @GrafZahl I see. So basically it is only injective if the kernel is trivial which is equivalent to saying the kernel consists of only the neutral element?

Comment: Exactly, a homomorphism is injective iff the kernel contains no elements other than the neutral element.

Comment: @GrafZahl Ah I see that makes sense. I always thought it had to be 0 but I was wrong. Thank you for your help

Comment: @GrafZahl Sorry for the late follow-up question, but I thought about this exercise again and was now wondering: if $f(x) = g*x*g^{-1} = g*g^{-1}*x=e*x=x$ , can I just rewrite it as such or would that be a mistake? Also for surjectivity this would make solving it easier?

Comment: @GrafZahl Why not an official answer?

Comment: @23408924 Not every group is abelian, i.e. in general you don't have $a*x=x*a$, so this cannot be used.

Comment: @PaulFrost Sometimes I just start writing a comment and end up with an answer ^^